# Odoo Controller base64 image encode to base64 decode

Tags: postgresql, api, odoo

currently i have to build Odoo API to get image base64 code via postman and store into odoo database as image.
I want to ask how to decode base64 encoded image into odoo controller and store image into database?

Comment: Check the [web_unsplash](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/fe7515736e3a5d1c1df028b2fb249c07dfa8f375/addons/web_unsplash/controllers/main.py#L93-L118) module, it converts an image content then create an attachment

Comment: Any example code getting base64 code of image from Android to Odoo Controller to decode to image